# how to append the object of array to checkbox with the help of variable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular10

I am having 5 rows with 120 checkboxes each
those checkboxes are door value stored in form of an array those checkboxes are having two attributes one in a row no and the other is door value (doorId)
if I am checking on one door on that value I am storing the door id and row no as an object of the array
that array I am storing in backend and after that, I am fetching that values and storing the opened door in an array

now what I need to do that am getting the array of the open door that means doorid and row no
I want to append that value to the checkbox so that when the door will be opened it will get a check and if the door is closed it will be unchecked

I tried that with **getElementById** but I am not able to use the checkbox as I am not having a boolean value to append to the checkbox

```
      (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("doorSelected" +k1+this.channelReference));
```

my HTML code

```
                                    <tr *ngFor="let doors of totalDoors;let k=index;">

                                        <div id="ck-button">
                                            <label style="margin-bottom: unset;">
                                               <input type="checkbox"  id="doorSelected{{k}}{{i}}" value={{doors.doorName}}
                                               class="door{{k}}"
                                             (change)="onChangeCat(doors.doorName, $event.target.checked,k)">
                                             <span>{{doors.doorName}}</span>
                                            </label>
                                         </div>
                                      
                                    </tr>
                                </div>[enter image description here][1]
```

this is my output i want to appended in checkbox
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkFsF.png